Is this the correct way to integrate orientation given torque and inertia tensor?
I am trying to develop a 3D rigid body simulation in C++ in which I had some conceptual doubts on how to integrate for orientation given the total torque applied to a rigid body, and it's initial inertia tensor. Currently my procedure looks something like this:
  Matrix transformed_inertia_tensor = rotation_matrix * inertia_tensor * transpose(rotation_matrix);
  Vector rotation_acceleration = inverse(transformed_inertia_tensor) * torques;
  Vector new_rotation_velocity = rotation_velocity + rotation_acceleration * time_step;
  rotation += (rotation_velocity + new_rotation_velocity) * time_step / 2.0;
  rotation_velocity = new_rotation_velocity;

The rotation_matrix is recalculated then using the new rotation vector. I assume the magnitude of the rotation vector is the angle, and the normalised rotation vector as the axis of rotation to calculate the new matrix, but I am not sure I can just add vectors representing axis-angle orientation like that.
I am also unsure about how to transform the intertia_tensor from object to world space. Currently, I am doing matrix multiplications with the transformation matrix.
Is what I am doing conceptually correct? Of course any direct confirmation that what I am doing is correct, or incorrect, would be helpful.

The answer is given in the literature. Links to all the notes is given here.

Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

The equations $~ \begin{aligned}I\dot \omega +\omega \times I\omega =\tau \
I=RI_{k}R^{T}\
\dot\phi =f\left( \omega \right) \end{aligned}$ $~R=R(\phi)~$

There are various approaches in the literature that deal with encoding rotations and their integration. I think the simplest to implement in a computer system is to use momentum to track the motion of the object and quaternions to encode the rotations.
I am answering from a physics standpoint (since this is not a programming forum).
The following table summarizes the physical quantities that you need to track
$$\begin{array}{c|cc|l}
\text{Quantity} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Size} & \text{Definition}\\
\hline \text{Position Vector} & \boldsymbol{r} & 3 & {\rm pos}(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{Orientation Quaternion} & \boldsymbol{q} & 4 & {\rm rot}(\boldsymbol{\hat{n}},\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\\
\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{Rotation Matrix} & {\rm R} & 3×3 & {\rm R}={\rm rot}(\boldsymbol{q})\\
\text{Momentum} & \boldsymbol{p} & 3 & \boldsymbol{p}=m\,\boldsymbol{v}\\
\text{Angular Momentum} & \boldsymbol{L} & 3 & \boldsymbol{L}={\rm I}\boldsymbol{\omega}\\
\text{Velocity} & \boldsymbol{v} & 3 & \boldsymbol{v}=\tfrac{1}{m}\boldsymbol{p}\\
\text{Rotational Velocity} & \boldsymbol{\omega} & 3 & \boldsymbol{\omega}={\rm I}^{-1}\boldsymbol{L}\\
\text{Net Force} & \boldsymbol{F} & 3 & \text{<sum of applied forces>}\\
\text{Net Torque} & \boldsymbol{\tau} & 3 & \text{<sum of torques about COM>}
\end{array}$$
Specifically, the state of each object is completely defined by the following 13 component vector
$$\mathcal{Y}=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{r}\\
\boldsymbol{q}\\
\boldsymbol{p}\\
\boldsymbol{L}
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the integration step involves the integration of quaternions (found elsewhere in literature) and Netwton's 2nd law (as well as Euler's law of rotation)
$$\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\mathcal{Y}=\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{m}\boldsymbol{p}\\
\tfrac{1}{2}\Omega\boldsymbol{q}\\
\boldsymbol{F}\\
\boldsymbol{\tau}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\Omega=\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{\omega}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ is a quaternion form of the rotation vector and\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Quantity} & \text{Derivative}\\
\hline \text{Positon} & \tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{r}=\tfrac{1}{m}\boldsymbol{p}\\
\text{Orientation} & \tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{q}=\tfrac{1}{2}\Omega\boldsymbol{q}\\
\text{Momentum} & \tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{p}=\boldsymbol{F}\\
\text{Angular Momentum} & \tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{L}=\boldsymbol{\tau}
\end{array}
Now periodically the orientation quaternion $\boldsymbol{q}$ is going to drift from being a unit quaternion and would need to be re-normalized to have a magnitude of one after each integration step.

For reference here is some Fortran code to evaluate the state vector rate
elemental function body_get_motion(rb, current) result(v)
class(rigidbody), intent(in) :: rb
type(state), intent(in) :: current
type(motion) :: v
real(wp) :: R(3,3), M(3,3)
    R = rot(current%ori)
    M = rb%inertia(R, .true.)
    v%vee = current%mom / rb%mass
    v%omg = matmul(M, current%agl )
end function

elemental subroutine body_set_motion(rb, current, v)
class(rigidbody), intent(in) :: rb
type(state), intent(inout) :: current
type(motion),intent(in) :: v
real(wp) :: R(3,3), I(3,3)
    R = rot(current%ori)
    I = rb%inertia(R, .false.)
    current%mom = rb%mass * v%vee
    current%agl = matmul(I, v%omg)
end subroutine

elemental function body_calc_rate(rb, current, f) result(rate)
class(rigidbody), intent(in) :: rb
type(state), intent(in) :: current
type(loading), intent(in) :: f
type(state) :: rate
type(motion) :: v
    v = rb%motion(current)
    ! d(r)/dt = v
    rate%pos = v%vee
    ! d(q)/dt = 1/2*ω*q
    rate%ori = q_der(current%ori, v%omg)            
    ! d(p)/dt = F
    rate%mom = f%force
    ! d(H)/dt = τ
    rate%agl = f%torque        
end function


That you very much, this is really helpful. I'll also look in to the notes you shared.
